# TensorFlow Docker Images

Tags: docker, tensorflow

When using the general TensorFlow docker images, they won't be optimized for the exact target architecture.

a) Are there studies for the performance penalty for using these general docker images vs. compiling for the specific architecture?

b) When using a orchestration system such as KubeFlow/Mesos across a heterogeneous cluster, what are best practices for mapping nodes to the optimized TensorFlow compilation (e.g., installing it on each node, having multiple docker images....).

Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

For the performance, you can have a look at [breandangregg container performance analysis](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-05-15/container-performance-analysis-dockercon-2017.html)
It's quite good, due to dockerizing is more similar to doing chroot than virtualization, because containers share some kernel functions.

Best practice for heterogeneous cluster is to have a set of images. 
For each image, you can run containers with different configuration passing environment variables. 
If configuration is going to be the same, you can use autoscaling function of kubernetes, for example.